# Postgresql - requests on rarely used data slow everything

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have a problem with a postgresql database which slow down when some requests are done on old rarely used data.

This database contains data on appointments, messages, etc. Everything is dated, and requests are mostly for current and future times. Data about old appointments and messages is rarely used, but still needed for accounting and history.

On normal times, the server is very responsive. The web app show a 40ms response time with 15k requests per minute, 80ms on high traffic days (20k requests per minute).
The database is about 120GB in size.
The debian server memory is fulled used, roughly 2GB by postgresql and 29GB in disk cache.
Disk I/O usage show only disk writes, nearly no disk read.

However, if I make a request on old data, for example statistics on appointments made 2 years ago, the server show massive disk read spike (as expected), but meanwhile every other request is slowed down. The web app show a 250ms+ response time for the duration of the request.
The cpu usage doesn't really increase while this is happening, staying at 40-60% usage.

This lag spikes are happening multiple times per day, and are really annoying, even if not critical. Anyone have any idea on how to reduce or eliminate this problem?

Comment: First that comes to my mind , is index issue.  Try to analyse the executed query which selects old data.
BTW, it's hard to suggest any solution, because the responsiveness of server depends not only on DB size and memory, but also the DB structure and executable query.

Comment: Same requests on recently used data don't provoke the problem.
The only difference is if the data was recently and frequently used or not. So basically if the data is in the disk cache or not.
And I think it's normal to see disk reads for those infrequent requests. However, WHY does it slow down everything else until the request is finished??

Comment: What is your disk array like?  What is your filesystem?  What is the full distribution name and kernel version?  What the is `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of the query against the old data, and the same thing for a "normal" query during the time when it is getting slowed down? (Please turn track_io_timing on before running those).  Does the performance go back up instantly when the query against old data finishes, or does it take some time before it returns to normal?

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. As long as you don't have enough memory to cache the whole database, rarely used data will not be cached and have to be read from disk. This is naturally slower.

To improve that, there are two options:

1. get enough RAM to cache the whole database
2. get faster storage

Comment: My subquestion would be: is it normal that is slow down EVERY requests while it's doing the slow one?

Comment: No, unless you have a really lame I/O subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved programmaticlly.As you mentioned, your data includes hot data and cold data, whcih is divided by dates.So just divide hot data and cold data into two tables.
You can migrate cold data to a archived table automaticlly.And then every request should specify time range to search.For example, if the request requested current and future times, then access hot data table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure it will resolve the problem, as the performance impact affect every other request while the "cold" request is performed, but it's an interesting thing to try. At the least, this should lighten the "hot" tables greatly,

Comment: @BenoitConnault this solution is similiar to ```partition```, which will shrink per table size.And there will be less records to scan and queries will be faster.

Comment: For detail information about partition in postgresql, you can reference https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-table-partitioning-scale-postgresql